# Combine two files by a column and add 0 when entry is missing

Tags: text-processing

I have two files as below. I am trying to figure out a way to create a master file containing all entries from file 1 and second column of file 2 by adding 0 wherever entry is missing in file 2. All these files are tab seperated. I tried `join` command, but could not get it to work.

- Example of `File1`

  ```
  orange
  banana
  berry
  cherry
  strawberry
  ```
- Example of `File2`:

  ```
  orange   1   
  banana   2   
  cherry   1
  ```
- Desired output

  ```
  Output    Value
  orange     1
  banana     2
  berry      0
  cherry     1
  strawberry 0
  ```

What I tried:

```
join File1 File2 |less
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to include some more details: (1) How are the columns delimited (space/tab/...)? (2) Do you want to have the "Header" line in the output? (3) Which order should the lines in the output be? That of `File1` or that of `File2` (if they can be different)?

Comment: Yes, I added the information you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
$ join -a 1 -e 0 -o 0,2.2 <(sort File1) <(sort File2)
banana 2
berry 0
cherry 1
orange 1
strawberry 0
```

This uses `join` to perform a relational JOIN operation between the files.  This requires both files to be sorted, which is why we sort them in a process substitution each (you could obviously pre-sort the data if you wish).  The command will list all lines from the first input file (`-a 1`) and replace missing fields with `0` (`-e 0`).  The fields in the output will be the join field (the first field in each file by default, and written `0` in the argument of the `-o` option) and the second field from the second file (`2.2`).

Pro: Fast (especially if the data is already sorted) and memory-efficient.
Con: Re-orders the data.

---

To preserve the order of the original `File1`, you may use `awk` instead:

```bsh
$ awk 'NR == FNR { key[$1] = $2; next } { $2 = ($1 in key) ? key[$1] : 0 }; 1' File2 File1
orange 1
banana 2
berry 0
cherry 1
strawberry 0
```

This reads the 1st column of `File2` as keys in the `key` associative array, and the 2nd column as their associated values.

When `File1` is being read (`NR` is no longer equal to `FNR`), we set the 2nd column to either the value from the `key` array, if there is a key corresponding to the 1st column, or to `0` if there is no such key.

You may shorten the code somewhat by abusing the fact that a uninitialized value is zero in arithmetic contexts:

```bsh
$ awk 'NR == FNR { key[$1] = $2; next } { $2 = 0+key[$1] }; 1' File2 File1
orange 1
banana 2
berry 0
cherry 1
strawberry 0
```

Pro: Output is ordered according to `File1`.
Con: Data from `File2` is stored in memory (only really matters if reading huge number of lines).

Comment: This is a very good example of how to use join command. Thanks THEY for this clever answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any command that can do that, but it can be scripted:

```bsh
while IFS='' read -r l1; do
  grep "^${l1}" File2 || echo -e "${l1}\t0"
done < <(cat File1)
```

Comment: That will fail when the lines from FIle1 contain regexp metachars, are substrings of  strings in File2, etc. and it'll be extremely slow. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Note that `< <(cat File1)` is a roundabout way of writing `<File1`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using `awk`, but it requires buffering `File2` (so if you have *huge* files you may hit a limit, although usually that is unlikely).

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     !mainfile{val[$1]=$2;next}
     {if ($1 in val) {$2=val[$1]} else {$2=0}} 1' File2 mainfile=1 File1
```

It works as follows:

- Before processing anything, we set the input and output field separator to TAB.
- While processing the first input file (`File2` in this case), indicate by the variable `mainfile` being uninitialized, we simply record the "value" for each of the "fruits" in an associative array `val`. After that, we immediately skip processing to the next input line (and skip the part that should only apply while processing `File1`).
- Before processing the next file, `awk` will first evaluate the `mainfile=1` statement to set `mainfile` to, well, `1`.
- Once `mainfile` is set, the first rule is ignored, and we only process the second rule. Here, we check if there is a "value" mapped to the entry in column 1. If so, we use that value for column 2, otherwise we set column 2 to `0`.
- The seemingly stray `1` outside of the rule blocks instructs `awk` to print the current line, including any modifications made.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something you can hack together very quickly in python

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Overly grande solution to the problem posed in the question.
"""
import sys

# Check whether the user specified two arguments to the script
if not len(sys.argv) == 3:
  sys.stderr.write(f"Usage: {sys.argv[0]} File1 File2")
  sys.exit(-1)

# Empty dictionary
dictionary = {}

# Fill the dictionary with zero-entries from the first file
with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
  for line in file:
   dictionary[line.strip()] = 0

# Replace the zero entries when found in second file
with open(sys.argv[2]) as file:
  for line in file:
    entry, value = line.split()
    dictionary[entry] = int(value)

# print the result table
print("Output\tValue")
for key, value in dictionary.items():
  # We're using the format string syntax to give the count
  # field a constant length of 8, so that things are nicely
  # right-aligned.
  print(f"{key}\t{value:8}")
```

Comment: I tried this method and its giving me duplicate row entries
Output Value
orange
        0
banana
        0
berry
        0
cherry
        0
strawberry
        0
orange        1
banana        2
cherry        1

Comment: aaaah yes, my bad, the lines of the first file are read such that every entry contains the "newline" character at the end of the line. Fixing that by using `strip`... (there should be a line break after every 0-count entry, is that right?)

Comment: Thank you. that worked perfectly

Comment: you're welcome! If an answer helps you, you should generally feel encouraged to upvote it!